# What if you don't feel like you'r the same person when you'r committing a sin?

Tags: salat, ramadan, eid

What if you feel like your not the person you are when you commit a sin meaning if I committing a sin I don't feel like it's me doing it but then after I realized it is me. I don't understand why it's like that because I never in my senses when I am committing a sin and I regret it right after and hate myself. But I always felt that its not me that is doing it, like I always feel like someone is controlling me and I cant stop them. After I always feel guilty for not stopping myself from committing a sin?

Answer (score 0):

First of all understand that everyone is on a different path. Some have easy, some have difficult and some have something in between. Allah created free will. Allah does what he wants, what's good and best for all his creation. He does not necessarily announce forgiveness.

You should keep a positive intention when you think you are commiting a sin, and if it becomes a sin, repent. Following Allah's commands is easy, difficult or somewhere in middle according to what he has planned for you. You should not worry too much. Just your intention is enough as the prophet said, just the intention of doing a task is better than doing the task itself.

Comment: Honestly that helped me a-lot, thanks a lot for the fist question and also for the second  questions.

Answer (score 0):

**There is not a single person who doesn’t sin. Period.** 
Believe me, I’ve been in your place countless amount of times. 
*Did I really just do this? Did I really just do that? How will god ever forgive me? Is there even hope for a man like me?*

Allah says:

> If the disbelievers knew about my mercy, none of them would ever think they would be able to enter hell. If the believers knew how strong my punishment is, none of them think they would ever be able to escape hell.

Allah also says:

> Oh my slaves. If your sins reached the heavens, and you don’t associate partners with me in Ibadah, and you’re asking for my forgiveness, I will come to you with mercy and forgiveness that match your sins. My slave, if you were to ignore me, neglect me, sin, never pray, become the worst person, the worst, the filthiest person—the biggest criminal. And **once**, only **once**, in your life, something enters your heart, and you say to me ya Rabb! I will respond, “yes my slave. What do you want?”

**Never think the mercy of Allah will run out.**

That guilt you face, cherish it. It shows you still have faith. It shows you’re not a victim to the harden heart. The heart that wouldn’t feel remorse over disobeying it’s Lord.
You still have that remorse, don’t ever let that heart harden, or else you’ll never feel bad for disobeying your Lord, and will never repent.

Never think you shouldn’t repent after sinning, nor decide to wait because you feel too dirty. That’s the trick of the Shaytaan. He wants you to think “Oh, Allah will be too mad at you to accept your forgiveness. Repent later, you’re too dirty.” No! Repent now! Who says you have the next second to live?

I have watched numerous of Islamic videos over forgiveness, repenting, and the mercy of Allah. It has really improved my overall mentality whenever I sin and feel bad. Now I know Allah is here for me, and awaits my repentance whenever, even when you intentionally sin, never think Allah won’t accept your repentance.

When you sin, quickly follow it up with a good deed. And the best thing to do after sinning is to recite the Shahada. Saying this will replenish your faith, it will clean your heart. It’s like dipping a hot metal rod inside a bucket of ice. That’s how much the Shahada would make an impact.